# Проблема с сертификатом

Tags: linux, ubuntu

### На GUI версии Oppenconnect не работает .pfx

Поэтому для Openconnect приходится разбивать pfx на 3 файла

```
openssl pkcs12 -in *.pfx -nocerts -out key.pem
openssl pkcs12 -in *.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out cert.pem
openssl pkcs12 -in *.pfx -cacerts -out vpn.crt
```

такими командами сработало в ноябре прошлого года, но сейчас словил непонятную ошибку

```
    Error outputting keys and certificates
4077F0DB5F7F0000:error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:../crypto/evp/evp_fetch.c:349:Global default library context, Algorithm (RC2-40-CBC : 0), Properties ()
```

В интернете не смог найти решение этой проблемы
может кто-то сталкивался и знает что делать..
Версия openssl - 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.7, а Ubuntu - Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить к команде в самом конце ключ **-legacy**

Comment: О да, это помогло)
Спасибо вам огромное!